# エラーが取れないです。No route matches [PATCH] "/articles/1/comments"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

記事についたコメントを編集出来るようにしたいのです。
コメントをformに持っていき編集して更新ボタンをクリックすると
No route matches [PATCH] "/articles/1/comments"
のようなエラーが出てきてrotesなどを色々変えて見たのですが全然、治らないので見ていただけないでしょうか？
_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(comment, url: article_comments_path) do |f| %>
<% if comment.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %></h2>
  <ul>
  <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :content %>
<%= f.text_area :content %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :article_id %>
<%= f.number_field :article_id %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
rails.application.routes.draw do

get '/users' => 'users#index'
get '/users/:id' => 'users#show'
devise_for :users
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end

# For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.'}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article } and return

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :article_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、`new` で、`@comment` が article と関連付けられていません。
以下のようにすると関連付けられます。

```
def new
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.build
end
```

同様に `edit` でも `@article` を設定しておきます。

```
def edit
  @article = @comment.article
end
```

で、`No route matches [PATCH] "/articles/1/comments"` については、

```
<%= form_for([article, comment]) do |f| %>
```

で治ります。
ただし、article も渡してやる必要があります。これは、`new.html.erb` や `edit.html.erb` で

```
<%= render 'form', comment: @comment %>
```

といった感じになっていると思いますので、以下のように追加します。

```
<%= render 'form', comment: @comment, article: @article %>
```

最後に、`update` メソッドの

```
    format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
```

でエラーが出ますので、

```
    format.html { redirect_to article_comment_path(@comment), notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
```

と修正すると解決します。